# Webdriver gives Timeout Exception running Codeception acceptance test

Tags: selenium, jenkins, safari, timeout, codeception

I have a long pipeline of Codeception acceptance test set up in Jenkins.  Safari regularly throws an \ScriptTimeoutException when starting a test (every 14 - 23 browser start throws this error). This does not happen on the same test each time the pipeline is started.

The exception prints as:

> [Facebook\Webdriver\Exception\ScriptTimeoutException]
>
> Timed out awaiting response to command "maximizeWindow" after 30002 ms
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 30.01 seconds

Currently, the safari environmental variable in acceptance.suite.yml looks like this:

```
safari:
     modules:
        config:
            WebDriver:
                browser: 'safari'
                window_size: 'maximize'
                clear_cookies: true
                restart: true
                options:
                    cleanSession: true
```

I've tried setting an exact window size and removing the window_size option entirely.  There did not appear to be any difference in the occurrence rate of this error.

Using Selenium server 2.53.1.  Safari version 9.1.2.  Jenkins version 2.16

Any ideas on who to reduce the number of times this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also got this error:

1) ListingRaceTestCest: Test events
 Test  tests/acceptance/ListingRaceTestCest.php:Login

[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeOutException]

Scenario Steps:

108. $I->waitForElementVisible(".rule-row-date",15)
109. $I->click("button#add-rule-btn")
110. $I->see("Configure payment rules")
111. $I->waitForElementVisible("#side-menu",15)
112. $I->pauseExecution()
113. $I->click("table#races-table tbody tr:first-child td:last-child button")

**I have found a solution now** and its working for me, try this hope it works for you!

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

This is setting for dynamic time you can change it accordingly. Codeception provides the execution time facility approx 5 min then it will give timeout error. 
This situation I got and now found the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding!  Where are you inserting this bit of code?

Comment: Please put it on the top of the file(Login) like this:

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");

ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

class LoginTestCest {